# Explanation about Miniconda environments

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm new using Jupyter on Miniconda and I was having a problem while importing packages (`ImportError: DLL load failed` ), looking for answers the solution was to initialize a base environment in my bash.

I used to initialize jupyter typing `jupyter notebook` in bash, but using the solution given, I have to activate `conda activate bash` and then type `jupyter notebook`. What is the difference between starting Jupyter the way I used to and this new way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conda activate` command activates a virtual environment. It is an isolated environment so all packages you installed in the virtual environment cannot be used outside it. When you start bash, you are in the `base` environment and it seems that you installed your Jupiter in `bash` environment so you cannot use bash's Jupiter in base environment and vice versa. It may be a little annoying at the beginning, but it can let you use different environments for different purposes. For example, since pip only allows one version of a specific package to be installed, different environments can let you test a new version of a package without breaking the functionality of the original program.